# Configuring my makefile for gdb

Tags: makefile, gdb, g++

I've used gdb before, but never with a makefile and only configuring in very simple ways. g++ -g -o file.cpp, etc. I've tried everything, and I cannot get it to recognize debugging objects. I want to debug all of my executable compile.

I'm running g++ and Ubuntu.

```
compile: scanner.o parser.o listing.o locals.o globals.o
    g++ -o compile scanner.o parser.o listing.o locals.o globals.o

scanner.o: scanner.c locals.h globals.h listing.h tokens.h
    g++ -c scanner.c

scanner.c: scanner.l
    flex scanner.l
    mv lex.yy.c scanner.c

parser.o: parser.c listing.h locals.h globals.h
    g++ -c parser.c

parser.c tokens.h: parser.y
    bison -d -v parser.y
    mv parser.tab.c parser.c
    mv parser.tab.h tokens.h

listing.o: listing.cc
    g++ -c listing.cc

locals.o: locals.cc
    g++ -c locals.cc

globals.o: globals.cc
    g++ -c globals.cc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not override the default rules.  Just assign CC and CFLAGS as necessary.  In other words, your Makefile should be (in its entirety):

```
CC=g++    # Not best practice.  See comments below
CFLAGS=-g
compile: scanner.o parser.o listing.o locals.o globals.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@  $^

scanner.o: scanner.c locals.h globals.h listing.h tokens.h
parser.o: parser.c listing.h locals.h globals.h

scanner.c: scanner.l
    flex scanner.l
    mv lex.yy.c scanner.c

parser.c tokens.h: parser.y
    bison -d -v parser.y
    mv parser.tab.c parser.c
    mv parser.tab.h tokens.h
```

As an aside, you really should use `CXX` to specify a C++ compiler and name your source code files appropriately.  (Use *.c for C, *.cxx for C++)  Since you are using non standard names, you need to fool make by using a C++ compiler for CC, which is not really the best practice.

Comment: running it exactly how you have it, make compile, gdb compile gives me a no debugging symbols found message. I thought this was supposed to indicate someone not using the -g flag?

Comment: Oops.  I have a glaring omission in the rule for `compile`.  Edited. (Although this probably will not fix the issue...must give more consideration.)

Comment: Did you do a make clean and rebuild the object files?  Watch the output of make and see if the `-g` flag is in the command lines.

Comment: I should've realized that was the problem... I had been deleting all the objects and rebuilding them, but I also missed putting the CFLAGS macro into compile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should also mention -O0 
if you want to avoid compiler optimised code